# Effective Project Management spanning multiple repos in Github

Tags: project-management, github

We've got a system called *Foo* hosted as a repository in Github.

The system depends on a couple more microservices, called *Bar* and *Baz*. Each of these microservices is hosted as a separate repository.

We are getting lost when doing Issue Tracking since there is no single repository where the Issues live. A single Feature request might create Issues across multiple repositories, which might or might not affect the code in the main *Foo* project.

How can we do effective Project Management with Github's tools in these cases?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/linking-a-repository-to-a-project-board/

Comment: @Ewan Sorry for not clarifying, we don't use Projects (nor do we want to). I'm talking about Issues/Milestones/Releases. Edited the question just now.

Comment: hmm bit confused MUST use GitHub tools, but not the one specifically designed for this use case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the different services are developed together, this can be an indication that they should really be maintained in a common repository (monorepo). Splitting your code across multiple repositories sounds clean and elegant, but in reality it often makes it hard to keep them in sync.

But let's say you don't have that option.

Then, use a separate issue tracker for cross-cutting concerns. This could be an external tool like Jira, or this could be an empty GitHub repository that you just use for the issue tracker. For the individual service repositories, you might want to keep the issue trackers for service-specific issues, or disable them entirely (you can still use pull requests).

Github's built-in issue tracker is better than nothing, but it is woefully inadequate for complex use cases. There's nothing wrong with using a different tool that fits your use case better, or using ways to [extend the GH issue tracker](https://github.com/works-with/category/project-management) with additional features.

Comment: I definitely think monorepo is a good idea here. Coordinating merge requests across many repos is a real pain, migrating to a monorepo eliminates this issue.

Comment: I've accepted this answer for the suggestion that I should use a monorepo, which is what we decided to go with.

Comment: @nicholaswmin A few years later, what were your experiences with going the monorepo route? DId it work out all right, or did you encounter other problems?

Comment: @anon I didn't go the monorepo route, I've created another repo exclusively for PM of the whole system. The system services are split in different GH repos.

Comment: @nicholaswmin Interesting, thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar situation. For issue tracking it may be best to use an external tool like Jira or trello.

Eventually I decided to merge all our projects into a single code repo, (since they all belonged to the same application). This way a merge request spanning multiple microservices can be reviewed at the same time, and you don't need to juggle many branches for one update.

Answer (score 1):

[**codetree**](https://codetree.com) will allow you to manage issues across multiple repos and allow other users to also manage them.

[Monday.com](http://Monday.com) will also allow this but it takes a ton of maintenance and configuration for each repo, and every time you add any repo.

I ran into the same issue of tying to manage issues across repos. @amon's answer (accepted answer) is not a solution for your question, but rather a possible solution for just your current scenario. In my scenario I have multiple repos, and specific users to access specific repos. Some of those users work on the issues in their cluster of repos, and the other users create the issues. All the repos are entirely separate projects, 3 or 4 are from 1 major project which was split across repos for a number of reasons.

**codetree** will allow you to group users into organizations. An organization can have multiple repo groups called projects. By default the members in an organization have access to the projects in it, but you can deny access to any project. Each user needs to have github access. So in each project it displays a grid with all the issues for all the repos in that project. You can create new, update, tag, comment on and close issues. It's really basic, but it has exactly what you (and I) are looking for. The downside is the free option only allows 1 user (yourself). And the free option isn't visible in the pricing page. I found it when I clicked to upgrade my free trial. 3 users is $24 USD monthly. Shame, I would think the 3 user package would be free to allow a small business to use it and purchase more users as they grow.

Answer (score -4):

I do not think that you can somehow influence this through the Github, but if you use any sort of compilers like Composer or NPM, then they have dependencies & finds out which versions of which packages can and need to be installed.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

But even here I think this is not very helpful, and it's best to look in the direction of the UnitTest, Smoke Testing, Regression Testing, Build Verification Test, Sanity Testing..

If all your code is described in the tests, then if you behave incorrectly or change the settings - you will immediately see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer has nothing to do with what I ask.